# Saving decoded and validated JWT/access tokens in Java

Tags: java, access-token, jwt

I'm an API Owner and will be decoding the JWT or access token passed on as part of the Authorization header for using my service. Since decoding is a costly process, I was planning to save the token in either a weak hash map or CacheBuilder

```
private Map cache = new WeakHashMap();
```

or

```
LoadingCache<Key, Graph> graphs = CacheBuilder.newBuilder()
   .expireAfterWrite(10, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
```

First, Is this a good practice?

Second, If not, what other options do I have apart from validating it every time?

Answer (score 2):

No, this is not a good practice (if you're talking about JWT in particular). One of JWT's main goals is to relieve the server from looking up any other place (session, local storage, DB). This way you can get really stateless API, server can serve a request the same way, no matter if it's a first client's request or 100th. Having this flexibility greatly reduces complexity of distributed deployment (i.e. cluster). Each node just needs to know how to verify the JWT (and decrypt it if encrypted), usually by simply providing it with a shared secret key. No session replication, no DB lookup, no inter-node communication.

The cost of examining token (check signature and decrypt if necessary), is negligible compared to DB lookup or session replication mechanisms. Your argument with hash map yields better performance only in case of single server node. Now days however, you want to program an API that is very easily deployed to a cluster.

What you need to decide is whether to encrypt the JWT or not (this can save some processing time). Usually encryption is not at all necessary and people just add it because it sounds 'more secure'. Think about the data you'll be putting in the token and can it be misused if it falls into wrong hands.

Comment: What I'm using is not a DB but a local server cache which is not replicated across nodes. I'm just trying to save the cost of decoding, verifying the signature and do some more thing, in my case, which needs a network call (get user details from the User identifier in the JWT). Also I looked at Spring Security and they seem to be using ehcache for similar reasons.

Comment: Don't do premature optimization. Try to see how slow actually decoding and signature verification works in practice. Then compare it to the execution of the request itself (biz logic). Measure it properly by executing stress tests. I'm almost sure it will be negligible. And for that 1% of slowing it down, you get the ability to deploy to cluster much easier. A good trade off isn't it?

Comment: Sorry but I'm still not convinced as I'm adding no additional components for deployment other than the maven pom file which I already have. Also I'm sure it's a situation worth optimization. I only had these questions 
1.Is this a good practice (Instance specific cache instead of distributed cache or DB and no Inter Node calls of exchanging this info. If an instance receives a token already validated by a some other instance, it would still validate it as it is not aware of what other instances have in their cache)?
2.What other options do I have "apart from validating it every time"?